# Changing the textarea field, HTML, JS, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, textarea

I have 7 buttons (different partner buttons with different images(logos)).

```
<a class="button button-type-1 fancybox_js" href="#buttonX">
<a class="button button-type-2 button-gray fancybox_js" href="#buttonX">
<a class="button button-type-2 button-orange fancybox_js" href="#buttonX">
```

As you see, they all have different  to open a modal window with textarea

```
<div class="hidden" id="buttonX">
    <div class="login-form">
        <div class="login-form-inner">
            <textarea id="button1" name="something"></textarea>
```

Inside of this textarea have to be the code of this button which was pressed

```
<a class="button button-type-1 fancybox_js" href="#buttonX"> if pressed this button
```

But I need to change the value of textarea depending which button was clicked.
If I click `<a class="button button-type-2 button-orange fancybox_js" href="#buttonX">` button, in the modal window I need to have a textarea with the code of this button.

How can I make this work?

Comment: So from what I understand, you have a modal window, which has code in it and few buttons. On clicking on button, you want to change some text. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sir.

Comment: Since value if textarea is read as string, you will have to replace it manually. As its has code, you can check for necessary identifier and replace value property. A proper working example would be better for us to help you.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle?

Comment: You can find here the live site.
http://plnkr.co/edit/vQj6nBEokBqE8rpuZwir?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the code of the button using jQuery's clone() and html() method.

I've added a class("myCBtn") to all your buttons and then cloning the button in `<div>`. After that you just need to take the HTML of created DIV to get the code of your button.

HTML of your buttons.

```
<td width="50%"><a class="button myCBtn button-type-1 button-blue-round fancybox_js" href="#buttonX"><span>Купить в кредит1</span></a><br>

<a class="button myCBtn button-type-1 fancybox_js" id="button_1" href="#buttonX"><span>Купить в кредит4</span></a><br>

<a class="button myCBtn button-type-2 button-gray fancybox_js" href="#buttonX"><span>Купить в кредит2</span></a><br>

<a class="button myCBtn button-type-2 button-orange fancybox_js" href="#buttonX"><span>Купить в кредит3</span></a><br></td>
```

Change following code

```
<div class="myCBtn" id="myCBtn">
    <textarea id="myCBtn" name="ButtonCode"></textarea>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="popupDivClass" id="popupDivId">
    <textarea id="buttonCodeTA" name="ButtonCode"></textarea>
</div>
```

Also remove below line.

```
document.getElementById('myCBtn').value = buttoncode;
```

And update the click function to following:

```
$('.myCBtn').click(function(e){
            var thisbutton=$(this).clone();
        var newDiv=$('<div>').append(thisbutton);
        var buttoncode=$(newDiv).html();
        // perform next operations here using buttoncode.
        $("#buttonCodeTA").val(buttoncode);
    });
```

Updated jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7o6p8nso/1/

Comment: Add the $('.myCBtn').click(function(e){ at the end of your page after adding jQuery library link.

Comment: Alok! You save my life! Thanks you very much! it works!

Comment: sorry, i forget with my happiness ;)
Once more thank you! Answer accepted!